# Великий и Могучий в masm32

Tags: консоль, кодировка, masm32, masm

Как вывести русскую строку на masm?

```
; #########################################################################

      .386
      .model flat, stdcall
      option casemap :none   ; case sensitive

; #########################################################################

    ; ------------------------------
    ; Build this app in console mode.
    ; ------------------------------

      include \masm32\include\windows.inc

      include \masm32\include\user32.inc
      include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
      include \masm32\include\masm32.inc

      includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

    ; ------------
    ; Local macros
    ; ------------
      print MACRO Quoted_Text:VARARG
        LOCAL Txt
          .data
            Txt db Quoted_Text,0
          .code
        invoke StdOut,ADDR Txt
      ENDM

      input MACRO Quoted_Prompt_Text:VARARG
        LOCAL Txt
        LOCAL Buffer
          .data
            Txt db Quoted_Prompt_Text,0
            Buffer db 128 dup(?)
          .code
        invoke StdOut,ADDR Txt
        invoke StdIn,ADDR Buffer,LENGTHOF Buffer
        mov eax, offset Buffer
      ENDM

      cls MACRO
        invoke ClearScreen
      ENDM

      Main   PROTO

; #########################################################################

    .code

    start:
      invoke Main
      invoke ExitProcess,0

; #########################################################################

Main proc

    LOCAL InputBuffer[256]:BYTE

  ; -------------------------------
  ; console mode library procedures
  ; -------------------------------

  ; ------------
  ; using macros
  ; ------------

    cls
    print "Поддержка латиницы",13,10,13,10

    input "Введи тут текст > "
    invoke StdOut,eax           ; return address in eax




Main endp

; #########################################################################

    end start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все как обычно - у Вас кодировка по умолчанию windows cp1251, а консоль в винде - это cp866. Соответственно у Вас есть три способа. Первый, самый простой - сохранять файл в кодировке cp866. Да, вначале нужно будет немного поправить текст, но все будет работать. Второй способ - кодировать явно. И есть даже [описание](http://sadda.ru/pages/assembler-masm32/chartooem/chartooem.htm). И третий, более красивый способ - использовать utf/unicode везде. В линуксе это обычно "изкоробки":).

Comment: Спасибо, первый способ помог :)

Answer (score 1):

Исходник сохраните в CP866. Это умеет делать [Bred](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bred)