# Не пишет на русском в Masm

Tags: c#, ассемблер, кодировка, masm32

Почему у меня не получается вывести текст на русском на Masm? Сделал программу которая конвертирует UTF8 в cp1251, потом сконвертированный текст вставляю в свою программу на masm которая должна перевести сначала мой текст из cp1251 в DOS и затем его вывести но она его почему-то не выводит, ну в смысле выводит но опять же не в той кодировке. Помогите пожалуйста, уже третий день ломаю голову :*(((

Первая программа - переводит UTF8 в cp1251 (C#)

```
string str = "Привет лол :D";
Encoding srcEncodingFormat = Encoding.UTF8;
Encoding dstEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
byte [] originalByteString = srcEncodingFormat.GetBytes(str);
byte [] convertedByteString = Encoding.Convert(srcEncodingFormat,
dstEncodingFormat, originalByteString);
string finalString = dstEncodingFormat.GetString(convertedByteString);
```

Вторая программа - переводит cp1251 в Dos и выводит получившуюсю строку (MASM).

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
 Main   PROTO 
 .data 
hConsoleInput DWORD ? 
 hConsoleOutput DWORD ? 
 NumberOfCharsWritten DWORD ? 
 _strochka byte "╨Я╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В ╨╗╨╛╨╗ :D", 0 
 .code 

 start: 
 invoke Main 
 invoke ExitProcess,0 
 Main proc 
invoke AllocConsole 
 invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE 
 mov hConsoleInput, EAX 
 invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE 
 mov hConsoleOutput, EAX    
invoke CharToOem, ADDR _strochka, ADDR _strochka
invoke WriteConsoleA, hConsoleOutput, ADDR _strochka, (SIZEOF _strochka), ADDR NumberOfCharsWritten, 0 
 Main endp 
 end start
```

Результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не, не помогает utf16

```
//UTF8 bytes
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is test string");

//Converting to Unicode from UTF8 bytes
byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, utf8Bytes);

//Getting string from Unicode bytes
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите на это - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484018/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-masm32 возможно там уже есть ответ.

Comment: Разница кодировок консоли(cp866) и приложения(cp1251). Только непонятно, зачем вам вообще такие извращения? Просто пишите строку в коде сразу в utf16, да выводите её в консоль через WriteConsoleW. Юникод в эмуляторе консоли(cmd) появился ещё во времена Windows 98.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov не не помогает, тему обновил

Comment: А как вы преобразуете строку в оную же пригодную для вывода?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ я сначала открываю notepad++, потом переключаю сначала кодировку с UTF8 в cp1251, ввожу нужный мне текст, а вот потом я преобразовываю всё это в UTF8 и всё ок. А вот в моей программе так не получается 

Comment: Я не понял, как именно вы в вашей программе делаете?